# Is there any env variable to turn --color (and the like) on for all commands?

Tags: command-line, colors

I do use aliases to turn on color for some commands by default. But I'm wondering if there's an easier way at telling my system, color is supported, don't make me use `--color` for `grep`, `ls`, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FreeBSD has [CLICOLOR](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls).

On Linux and any other system with GNU tools, you need to set LS_COLORS, GREP_COLOR, and GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto', but even then you still need to run `ls --color=auto`.  Run `info coreutils 'ls invocation'` for more details.

The easiest way I know to avoid typing `--color` on Linux is to make `ls` run `ls --color=auto` using an alias.

This is what I put in my .bashrc (well, really my .env, but it's like .bashrc) to make it happen by default:

```
# set default flags
if grep --color=auto --quiet "" "$HOME"/.bashrc >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  alias grep='grep --color=auto'
fi
if ls --color=never --directory / >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  # enable colors with GNU ls
  alias ls='ls --color=auto'
else
  alias ls='ls -F'
fi
```

Comment: GNU fails in this regard

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard for forcing colours.

`CLICOLOR` is increasingly common, and [there's an attempt to standardise it](https://bixense.com/clicolors/) too.

You can alias commands to provide the `--color=auto` (or equivalent) flag by default in your `.bashrc`, but you'll need to find the relevant flag for each command.